# using the control in UI-Thread issue?

Tags: c#, voip

What is the problem inside my work, I tried to use a UI Thread.

```
private void btn_Call_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MakeCall();
    }

private void MakeCall()
    {
        try
        {
            //Get the IP we want to call.
            otherPartyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtCallToIP.Text), 1450);
            otherPartyEP = (EndPoint)otherPartyIP;

            //Get the vocoder to be used.
            if (cmbCodecs.SelectedText == "A-Law")
            {
                vocoder = Vocoder.ALaw;
            }
               else if (cmbCodecs.SelectedText == "u-Law")
            {
                vocoder = Vocoder.uLaw;
            }
            else if (cmbCodecs.SelectedText == "None")
            {
                vocoder = Vocoder.None;
            }

            //Send an invite message.
            SendMessage(Command.Invite, otherPartyEP);             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "VoiceChat-Call ()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }          
    }
```

That returns the error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control ‘btn_Call’ accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the line that causes the problem in a call to the dispatcher:

```
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(...
```

From the error message you posted it's not clear what assignment is causing your issues. Might be one of these:

```
otherPartyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtCallToIP.Text), 1450);
otherPartyEP = (EndPoint)otherPartyIP;
vocoder = Vocoder.ALaw;
vocoder = Vocoder.uLaw;
vocoder = Vocoder.None;
```

Comment: I think the issue is how can I make controls delegate to use UI-Thread?

Comment: Florian, can you help me by reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the, post I can't figure out to apply for me.

Comment: Making the whole delegate run in the UI thread will block it. I dont know what SendMessage(Command.Invite, otherPartyEP); does, but your UI might get unresponsive when it takes long. I would suggest only to invoke the relevant stuff in the UI thread.

Comment: try it by editing my post to solve some problem.

Comment: Please post more exception information.

Comment: no more exception because the only one Exception is generated from: catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "VoiceChat-Call ()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

Comment: Change that line to MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "VoiceChat-Call ()", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);